# Update parent model with the HasOne child relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have a `League` model and a `Season` model their respective migrations and relationships.

`League` migration and relations

```php
Schema::create('leagues', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedBigInteger("id")->primary();
    $table->boolean("active");
    $table->string("name");
    $table->unsignedBigInteger("current_season_id")->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

```php
public function current_season()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Season::class);
}
```

`Season` migration and relations

```php
Schema::create('seasons', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedBigInteger("id")->primary();
    $table->string("name");
    $table->unsignedBigInteger("league_id");
    $table->boolean("is_current_season");
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

```php
public function league()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(League::class);
}
```

I have two vars with my models:

```php
$league = League::find(1);
$season = Season::find(10);
```

With this line, I know automatically `league_id` in the `Season` model is filled with the `$league->id`

```php
$season->league()->associate($league)->save();
```

I want do the inverse, and fill the `current_season_id` without doing:

```
$league->current_season_id = $season->id;
$league->save();
```

Is it possible?

Comment: It is possible , but I can see a circular reference issue in your models this can be tricky if you have foreign keys and when you try to delete record from any of your model it will throw exception and then you have to perform deletion in 2 steps , first remove reference then delete

Comment: Do you have any proposal or other way to do it to improve it?

Comment: You already have `is_current_season` bit in your seasons table , I believe it is per league so you don't need `current_season_id` in your league table

Comment: You see it better with my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the comments from @M Khalid Junaid, I think it´s better this way:

- Remove `current_season_id` from `League` model.
- Rewrite the `current_season` relation to this way:

  ```php
  public function current_season()
  {
       return $this->hasOne(Season::class)->where("is_current_season", true);
  }
  ```

Now, in this way, I can access the current season of the league in the form: `$league->current_season`

Thank you.

Comment: Yes its better this way , great effort

Answer (score 0):

1. You do not need `$table->unsignedBigInteger("current_season_id")->nullable();` in leagues table, if you are using hasOne relationship, otherwise you need another type of relationship.
2. I'd strong recommend in seasons table, to use a foreign key declaration in your migration

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger("league_id");
$table->foreign( 'league_id' )->references( 'id' )->on( 'leagues' );
```